# Automate setting of variables with foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm manually setting variables as in the example below.

There must be way to automate this and pass all of the variables from $data at once. I know foreach $data as won't work on it's own because of the 'resume' modifier.

Any help with the syntax of the loop would be greatly appreciated.

Sample:

```
$layout->set("name", $data['resume']['name']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

```
foreach($data['resume'] as $key=>$value){
  $layout->set($key,$value);
}
```